# how to set permission to file while creating a new file in data/data/com.xx.xx/ directory

Tags: android, android-studio

File file_address contains address of my `data/data/package` directory

I am setting permission as

```
file.setReadable(true,false);
file.setExecutable(true,false);
file.setWritable(true,false);
```

My file created there with permission `-rw-------`, but I want permission like `-rwxrwxrwx`

What should i do?

```
void downloadFile(){

    try {
        URL url = new URL(download_file_path);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //connect
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file

        //create activity_main new file, to save the downloaded file
        File file = new File(file_address, filename_user);
        file.setReadable(true,false);
        file.setExecutable(true,false);
        file.setWritable(true,false);

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //Stream used for reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
        totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                pb.setMax(totalSize);
            }
        });

        //create activity_main buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0;

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            downloadedSize += bufferLength;
            // update the progressbar //
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                    float per = ((float)downloadedSize/totalSize) * 100;
                    cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize + " / " + totalSize + " (" + (int)per + "%)" );
                }
            });
        }
        //close the output stream when complete //
        fileOutput.close();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // pb.dismiss(); // if you want close it..
            }
        });

    } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
        showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        showError("Error : IOException " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
    }
}

void showError(final String err){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(CSE_Secondyr.this, err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `i want permission like -rwxrwxrwx` -> No you don't. This will give anyone full write access. It's a very bad idea.

Comment: but i am not able to open the file in my application... It says read only. What should i do now?

Comment: improve text of question, improve code output